# Difference between exp and expdp

Tags: oracle

I am a newcomer to database administration. Can someone briefly explain to me the difference between commands `exp` and `expdp`?

Comment: you can also see : http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/dp_overview.htm#sthref14

Comment: This is a Google question - if you're having difficulty with something specific, then get back to us. Check out the forum tour and the "help us to help you" (and links within) blog - both at the bottom left of the page. Also check out the Help Centre - [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/review/close/53539#). These forums are a great resource and you will get more out of them by following the guidelines. p.s. welcome to the forums :-)

Answer (score 2):

The main difference compared to the architecture of Data Pump utility exp / imp and expdp / impdp are always run on the DB server and not on a client. Then the files will always on the server where and active an Oracle database.
The advantages of the data pump is performance (eg. Parallel) and the presence of new features' (eg. Migration direct SQL * Net, native compression, remap).
See this  [Oracle white paper(Upgrading to Oracle Database 12c)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/upgrade/upgrading-oracle-database-wp-12c-1896123.pdf)  on page 14.
You can also see the [Database Utilities](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/dp_overview.htm#sthref14) manual.